# Jacoco maven plugin prepare-agent goal getting added twice

Tags: maven-3, jacoco-maven-plugin

**Tools :**

Maven 3.2

Maven Jacoco Plugin - version 0.5.5.201112152213

**Issue :**

Below is the jacoco pugin included in pom.xml

```
<build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
            <configuration>
              <destFile>${basedir}/target/reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
              <dataFile>${basedir}/target/reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

After running effective-pom , I am getting below output -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-site</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <destFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
      <dataFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
      <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It seems that prepare-agent goal has been included twice . The redundant goal is

`<id>agent</id>` which is not present in `pom.xml` file and haven't been added.

So , my question is : why is this goal getting included in pom even though  the goal is already configured explicitly with id  `<id>jacoco-initialize</id>.`

**EDIT  :**

Further digging deep into problem , I removed the plugin `(jacoco-maven-plugin)` altogether from child module and when I run `mvn help:effective-pom` , interestingly it is still showing `jacoco-maven-plugin` with only one goal in it as below . It is the same one which gets added additionally. That means parent module is adding this plugin . But there is no reference of this plugin in parent module

```
<execution>
        <id>agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>C:\JDeveloper\mywork\myAppTest/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Comment: @Dur : The question was not to you . Sorry . I have edited the question to give some more details . Please have a look.

Comment: Maybe you have a parent of the parent or a dependency with a plugin management section?